# Endpoint URL not found in axios PUT endpoint

Tags: javascript, mysql, axios, put, endpoint

When pressing a button, my app is suppose to subtract 1 from the current Quantity in the database where the name of the item is "CrossBag"

My PUT endpoint on the client:

```js
confirm = () => {
    axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/merch/CrossBag`, {
        Quantity: this.state.merchInfo[0].Quantity - 1,
        });
};
```

The structure of my table merch where Name is the primary key:
[image]

The server side of the endpoint:

```js
app.put('/merch/:name', function (req, res) {
  const { name } = req.params;
  const { Quantity } = req.body;

  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
     if(err) {
         console.log(err)
         return
     }

     connection.query(`UPDATE merch SET Quantity = ${Quantity} WHERE name = ${name}`, function (error, results, fields) {
       
      if (error)
      {
        throw error;
      }
    });
   });
});
```

When I press the button though it states:

```
PUT http://localhost:5000/merch/CrossBag 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm a bit confused on how to update specifically that row's Quantity. I read that you need some kind of ID to specify which row to change, so I made that ID my Primary Key (Name).

Can anyone provide me any guidance?

Comment: have you tried app.put('/merch/CrossBag') ?

Comment: Here in your endpoint, u have to change to accept the params   `app.put('/merch/:name', function (req, res) {
let name = req.params.name;
//.... continue your logic

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the route like below:

```
// this will match route like /merch/CrossBag or /merch/Blanket
app.put('/merch/:name', function (req, res) {
  const {name = '' } = req.params; 
  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
     if(err) {
         console.log(err)
         return
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of doing const {name = '' } = req.params;?  Also, if I am using mySQL, would I have to restart it in order to see the new results, or should it be automatic by doing SELECT * from merch?

Comment: req,params.name contain the value you passed. for e.g merch/Blanket then the value of name will be Blanket. You can use this value for updating the quantity

Comment: UPDATE merch SET Quantity = ? WHERE name = ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my server code. Would you be able to help me figure out why I get this error: sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'CrossBag' in 'where clause'", The SQL seems correct: 'UPDATE merch SET Quantity = 1 WHERE name = CrossBag'

Comment: Just change the query string to `UPDATE merch SET Quantity = ${Quantity} WHERE name LIKE '${name}'`. Notice the `LIKE` keyword and the single quotes surrounding the name.

Comment: Oh that works! Thanks so much for the guidance!

Comment: connection.query("UPDATE merch SET Quantity = ? WHERE name = ? ", [req.body.Quantity, name], (error, result) => { // do login here})